# Can I capture the execution of a function? How to do it?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I want to make an Actor component in Unreal.
I want owning actor to has zero dependencies from the component.
I want to handle some owning actor events from the component.

I can get a pointer to the owning actor from the component using the GetOwner() function.

```
APlayerController *Controller = Cast<APlayerController>(GetOwner());
```

I can get a reference to the function I want to handle... for example

```
 &APlayerController::BeginPlay.
```

I know the signature of the function too.

This is the only information available if I want zero dependencies.

I want to capture the execution of the owner's function. That is, I want another function belonging to the component to be executed at the same time and receive the same parameters.

Is it possible to do it only using this information? How to do it?

---

UPDATE:
Ok: The example can be summarized in the following code. Pure C++. The Unreal API is not needed for this. I hope it is better understood that way. All I want is for ComponentFunction to be executed at the same time as ActorFunction and for param to have the same value.

```
class Actor;

class Component
{

    Actor *Owner;
public: 
    Component(Actor *actor)
    {
        Owner = actor;
    }

    void ComponentFunction(int param)
    {       
    }
    
};

class Actor
{
    
    Component *component;
public:
    Actor()
    {
        Component *component = new Component(this);
    }

    void ActorFunction(int param)
    {       
    }
};

int main()
{
    Actor *actor = new Actor();
    actor->ActorFunction(5);
    delete actor;   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but i can not use it. The component does not inherit from the owner (it is by composition).

Comment: Have you tried the unreal forums? This is more a question about their engine than it is about C++ . But maybe you can do something with a lambda expression

Comment: Yes i did it... none response for now... i'm using delegates right now. But I'd like to make it fully encapsulated. The point of a component is to be able to use it on different actors. Add and use... The ideal is not to add code in the owner. My post: https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/is-there-a-way-to-bind-owner-functions-from-a-component-fully-encapsulated/1275356

Answer (score 1):

With your update it sounds like you want ActorFunction to call ComponentFunction with the same param? If so:

```
void ActorFunction(int param)
{       
    component->ComponentFunction(param);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes, that is the easy way. And the thing i don't want to do.. :-) I want to do it from inside of the component and leave the ActorFunction "Empty". So the Actor never knows what is happening.... I thought there was a low level way to do this. But seeing the desert of answers I think there is none. At least in C++... Maybe in assembler. But I'm not going to kill myself on that. XD Thank you so much.

Comment: @IvánRodríguez what's the event in the actor that should trigger this? There's a ton of virtual functions in UActorComponent which you can override in a subclass (see source [here](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/release/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Classes/Components/ActorComponent.h) if you have access to UE GitHub), for example BeginPlay, EndPlay, etc.

Comment: Yes, they are virtual functions of the controller in this case. I want to make a component that works with APlayerController and AIController. Basically it is to verify that the Controller, GameState, and PlayerState have been replicated and are ready to be used. Yes, virtual functions exist, but they are not members of the UActorComponent class. For exaple(virtual void InitPlayerState() override;)Thanks for your reply.